# Does this creature have good head and neck balancing? Final(?) Draft

Tags: biology, creature-design, anatomy

I feel bad and guilty for doing this one AGAIN, but I've improved and want to further perfect my hyperfixation character. I've learned more of how things work from previous iterations, now I wish to see if I've learned enough to perfect the design. I wish there was some other place I could just have people critique the physiological soundness of my critters. If someone knows of a site that would better help me with my perfectionism anxiety, I'd love to hear it.

He is around 4 feet tall. Like birds, he has air sacs. That would lighten places.

My main concern is the head and neck operating properly and balanced. Not too heavy. Decent neck mobility and strength. Spinuous process space size. I wish to know does this work well?
Images:
[image: Dude side]
ignore the skull sketch, just look at the head size
[image: Dude front]

Comment: What is your question, and what has remained unanswered after the 6 answers you already got here https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/206594/30492 ?

Comment: There is no question mark in this question. What is the problem you want to solve? And how is this question different from the previous ones?

Answer (score 0):

Biologically speaking, the neck would need to be a little rigid to support the size, so not much mobility, but there is no way you can naturally offer more mobility with a big neck so it is totally okay!